# iOS Swift: Request user location

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, core-location

I'm a beginner in iOS Swift and writing iOS Swift code and using UIWebView to load my web page.

And my web page will **ask user to enable the user location**.

I would like to do the similar behavior in iOS Swift code (popup an dialog and say something like "TestApp would like to access your location. Would you agree?")

I'm running on Simulator and I failed while using CLLocationManager

The following is my Swift code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var customWebView: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://ctrlq.org/maps/where/") {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        customWebView.loadRequest(request)

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Anyone knows how to request location?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: Check NSHipster out for a good summary (for iOS 8, but still valid). Their article talks about the requirement to set up the key in info.plist: [NSHipster - Core Location in i​OS 8](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/) Also, _The user prompt contains the text from the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required when calling this method._ from [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/)

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to request and update user location(s) is via `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

While your View Controller inherits `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, it does not seem to implement the necessary delegate functions. As mentioned by @Rob, you should declare locationManager as a class property, not as a local variable.

This delegate function allows you to implement logic if/when user changes authorization status:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        // authorized location status when app is in use; update current location
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // implement additional logic if needed...
    }
    // implement logic for other status values if needed...
}
```

This delegate function allows you to implement logic if/when user location has changed:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
        // implement logic upon location change and stop updating location until it is subsequently updated
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Furthermore, `locationServicesEnabled()` determines whether the user has location services enabled.

Answer (score 8):

You show call do something like this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .NotDetermined || status == .Denied || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        // present an alert indicating location authorization required
        // and offer to take the user to Settings for the app via
        // UIApplication -openUrl: and UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "GPS access is restricted. In order to use tracking, please enable GPS in the Settigs app under Privacy, Location Services.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings now", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            }))
            // self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You've defined your `CLLocationManager` as a local variable, which will get released when it falls out of scope.

   Make this a property of your class.
2. If you really need `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, don't forget to set the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in the plist as outlined in the documentation.

   (And if you don't need always authorization, but are ok with "in use" authorization, call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` value.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in yours info.plist file and in the value you write something that you want to show the user in the popup dialog.
You need to test it on a real device cause Simulator accepts only custom locations.
Select the Simulator -> Debug -> Location -> Custom Location...

Comment: While the other answers give good tips for working with the location manager, this answer provides a "key" piece the OP was probably missing. It is required to provide the appropriate key value in the info.plist file. As far as the simulator goes, though - it is possible to test for the message the OP wanted to see using the simulator, regardless of custom location settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.your-url.com");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webview.loadRequest(requestObj);


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                print("Error with the data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(placemark.locality)
        print(placemark.postalCode)
        print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        print(placemark.country)

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.your-url.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webview.loadRequest(requestObj);


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            print("Error with the data.")
        }
    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```